# How to configure pip to use editable installs to fulfill requirements

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, requirements.txt

I'm trying to write a script that uses `mkvirtualenv` to re-make a virtual environment from the requirements recorded earlier with `pip freeze > <req_file>`. The original environment includes some [editable installs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) (setuptools develop mode installs) installed with `pip install -e <path>`, but you could not tell from correspending requirements which look like `<package>==<version>`.

When I run `mkvirtualenv -r <req_file>`, it passes the requirements file to `pip -r`. But `pip` fails because it is unable to find distributions for the editable installs.

How can I configure `pip` to know about the list of the paths originally specified to `pip -e` and use these [development eggs](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#overview) to fulfill requirements? I tried `find-links` in pip.conf (and `extra-search-dir` in virtualenv.ini) without success.

Comment: In `pip.FrozenRequirement.from_dist`, only editable installs from a VCS (e.g. `git+file:<path>#egg=<pkg>`) are accepted and will produce an `-e`-entry in the requirements file. But theses installs create a clone of the repository, so changes to the original source are not reflected. What I want is a non-VCS install during development.

Answer (score 3):

You can use -r in requirements files as well:

```
-e git+<Git-URL>
```

https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html

Comment: Thanks, that's true. But the requirement files are created by another script (which executes `pip freeze`) and I wouldn't want to have to edit them manually. And I haven't found an option for `pip freeze` to output more suitable requirements.